# Populate bootstrap-select with array of options

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-select

I created a table using [datatables](/questions/tagged/datatables) and on footer I added anempty dropdown select using [Bootstrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) as below :

```
<tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th><select class="selectpicker" multiple></select></th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

When my datatable is created, I want to add the distinct values of that column as options in my select.

The issue is : the datatable is drawn without errors but the select is not populated. It still shows empty but when i use inspect on browser I see the options are already inside the select.
[image]

I used `empty`before `append` and tried `html` instead of `append` but still not showing the options. I also tried [footerCallback](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html) instead of `initComplete`.

When I add the options manually inside my select in the html, it works fine. it looks like in datatable the footer is loaded before the body that's why it's not showing the options when it's displayed before the body is ready.

Any suggestions please how I could fixe it ? Thank you very much.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();

  $('#example').DataTable({
  "lengthChange": false,
  "info": false,
  "paging": false,
  "searching": false,
  
  initComplete: function () {
  this.api().columns().every( function () {
  var column = this;
  column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
  $('.selectpicker').append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' ) } ); 
   } );  }  }); });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.17/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.1/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.17/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>



<table id="example" class="table table-bordered" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Austria</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Japan</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Sweden</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Finland</td></tr>
    <tr><td>India</td></tr>
    <tr><td>USA</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Sweden</td></tr>
    <tr><td>France</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Austria</td></tr>
  </tbody>
   <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th><select class="selectpicker" multiple></select></th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov thanks for your time but i have it working with single input select as you sent. I am using Bootstrap-select so that users can use multiple select and be able to search from the dropdown.

Comment: Does it mean your real question is *'How to populate bootstrap multiselect with array of values?'*? Your current problem statement may seem somewhat misleading then (*'The issue is : the datatable is drawn without errors but the select is not populated'*)

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov  i updated the title, i had in mind to write it that way as in datatables there callback  functions you can apply directly on footer. Hope it's more clear now to people now. Thanks

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov thank you. It works now but only when the data is loaded inside html <tr><td>Austria</td></tr> but with serverside processing it's not working. the select doesn't show the options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake was initiating your selectpicker ***before*** populating it with options, whereas the opposite [is recommended](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/#via-javascript) in their reference docs.
Following is a fixed live-demo:

```js
$('#example').DataTable({
  lengthChange: false,
  info: false,
  paging: false,
  searching: false,
  
  initComplete: function(){
      const table = this.api();
      table.columns().every(function(){
        const title = $(this.header()).text();
        const options = this.data().unique().sort().toArray().reduce((options, item) => options += `<option value="${item}">${item}</option>`, '');
        $('.selectpicker').append(options).selectpicker()
      });
    }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.17/css/bootstrap-select.min.css"><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.1/umd/popper.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.17/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script><table id="example" class="table table-bordered" style="width:100%"><thead><tr><th>Country</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>Austria</td></tr><tr><td>Japan</td></tr><tr><td>Sweden</td></tr><tr><td>Finland</td></tr><tr><td>India</td></tr><tr><td>USA</td></tr><tr><td>Sweden</td></tr><tr><td>France</td></tr><tr><td>Austria</td></tr></tbody><tfoot><tr><th><select class="selectpicker" multiple></select></th></tr></tfoot></table>
```

Comment: thank you. It works now but only when the data is loaded inside html  <tr><td>Austria</td></tr> but with serverside processing it's not working. the select doesn't show the options :/

Answer (score -2):

You will need to initialize the selectpicker after you append the data not before.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#example').DataTable({
  "lengthChange": false,
  "info": false,
  "paging": false,
  "searching": false,
  
  initComplete: function () {
  this.api().columns().every( function () {
  var column = this;
  column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {

  $('.selectpicker').append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' ) } ); 
   } );  }  }); 
   
    // initialize the selectpicker after appending options
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
   });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.17/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.1/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.17/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>



<table id="example" class="table table-bordered" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Austria</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Japan</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Sweden</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Finland</td></tr>
    <tr><td>India</td></tr>
    <tr><td>USA</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Sweden</td></tr>
    <tr><td>France</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Austria</td></tr>
  </tbody>
   <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th><select class="selectpicker" multiple></select></th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```